# Issue with Saving Data into Database in Django using Instance

Tags: django, django-views

My Code is working but not saving into Database. I will like to know where the issue is coming from. However, I have tired my best in checking for the error. I am getting success message after submission. Please, kindly assist to fish out the issue. You can see from the below Picture attached with the question.

models.py

```
class Info(models.Model):
    MASJID_TYPE = (
        ('Ratibi', 'Ratibi'),
        ('Jummah Masjid', 'Jummah Masjid'),
        ('Central Masjid', 'Central Masjid'),

    )


    SECT = (
        ('Al-Sunnah', 'Al-Sunnah'),
        ('Salafee', 'Salafee'),
        ('Sufi', 'Sufi'),
        ('Ahamadiyah', 'Ahamadiyah'),

    )

    STATUS = (
        ('Completed', 'Complete'),
        ('Un-Completed', 'Un-Completed'),
        ('Proposed', 'Proposed'),


    )


    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    masjid_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=MASJID_TYPE)
    address = models.TextField()
    sect  = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=SECT)
    state  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    LGA = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=STATUS)
    history = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    founder = models.DateField("Founder Year", blank=False, null=False)
    latitude = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    longitude = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    congregation = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='masjid', blank=False, null=False)
    approval = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)




    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('masjid_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Imam(models.Model):

    CERTIFICATE = (
        ('PhD', 'PhD'),
        ('MSc', 'MSc'),
        ('Bsc', 'Bsc'),

    )

    masjid = models.ForeignKey(Info, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    imam_address = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    certificate = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CERTIFICATE)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    no_of_wives = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    no_of_children = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.first_name) + str(self.last_name) + str(self.masjid.name)
```

view.py

```
def newImam(request, pk):


    masjid = get_object_or_404(Info, pk=pk)
    masjid_info = masjid.id

    template_name = 'addimam.html'

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = ImamForm(request.POST, instance=masjid) 

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print(form.save)
            messages.success(request, 'The Project Details Has Been Added Successully!')
            return redirect('addimam', masjid.id) 
    else: 
        form = ImamForm(instance=masjid) 

    return render(request, 'addimam.html', {'form' : form,})
```

forms.py

```
class ImamForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Imam
        exclude = ('updated_at', 'created_at', 'masjid')
```

Comment: Instead of `print(form.save)` use `print(form.data)` . Look it in console: Are you getting any data from the form?

Comment: <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['ZxWDylUP0Ddv2j288Cl42Wx4VNRuJE3KIlwog1G1uhJhLSH4j9b5Yn92eQFWTQ1J'], 'first_name': ['Adewale'], 'last_name': ['Olaniyan'], 'imam_address': ['38, Tejumola estate, Opposite Fajol Hotel, Obantoko, Abeokuta'], 'phone_no': ['8151310066'], 'certificate': ['PhD'], 'occupation': ['Imam'], 'no_of_wives': ['1'], 'no_of_children': ['12']}>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def newImam(request, pk):

    masjid = get_object_or_404(Info, pk=pk)

    masjid_info = masjid.id

    template_name = 'addimam.html'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        #form = ImamForm(request.POST, instance=masjid)
        form = ImamForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.data)
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.masjid_id = masjid_info

            form.save()

            messages.success(
                request, 'The Project Details Has Been Added Successully!')
            return redirect('addimam', masjid.id)

    else:
        form = ImamForm(instance=masjid)

    return render(request, 'addimam.html', {'form': form})
```

Actually in here we can not send any instance since there is no data available for new imam. so you have to send the form data directly.